# Creating a fallback image for HTML5 video in email

Tags: email, html5-video, fallback

I am trying to create an email that has an embedded video in it, along with a fallback image in case the client doesn't support html5.

**Problem:** 
The issue I am running into is that, while the video works on compatible clients, **the fallback image does not display on browsers that are incompatible with the video**. I am very new when it comes to this stuff and don't know enough to identify where the problem is in the code I'm using.

Edit: Clarified what "incompatible" means.

```
<style type="text/css">

.video-wrapper {display:none;}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) and (min-device-width:1024px) 
{
    .video-wrapper { display:block!important; }
    .video-fallback { display:none!important; }
}

@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch) and (color:#ffffffff) 
{
    div[class^=video-wrapper] { display:block!important; }
    div[class^=video-fallback] { display:none!important; }
}

#MessageViewBody .video-wrapper { display:block!important; }
#MessageViewBody .video-fallback { display:none!important; }

</style>

<b>Video in Email Test</b><br>

<!-- video section -->
<div class="video-wrapper" style="display:none;">
<p> Video Content </p>
<video controls="controls" height="176" poster="https://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/Emailology/2013/html5_video/bunny_cover.jpg" srcset="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" width="320">

<!-- fallback 1 -->
<a href="https://www.emailonacid.com">
<img height="176" src="https://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/Emailology/2013/html5_video/bunny-fallback.jpg" width="320">
</a>

</video>
</div>
```

Comment: PS: Any clues on what an "incompatible one" is? _eg:_ How to recreate your problem for testing?

Comment: Ah, sorry, by "incompatible one" I mean "an email client that doesn't support embedded video" like gmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the article you took the code from](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/a_how_to_guide_to_embedding_html5_video_in_email/), you’re missing the following part that is supposed to act as a fallback:

```html
<!-- fallback section -->
<div class="video-fallback">
  <p>Fallback Content</p>
  <a href="https://www.emailonacid.com" ><img height="176" 
    src="https://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/Emailology/2013/html5_video/bunny-fallback.jpg" width="320" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: The fallback part was there. I've improved the code formatting to make it more visible.

Comment: No it is not there in the example. You have the `Fallback 1` part. But the code actually needs a second `fallback section` part. The first fallback is for cases where the email client would support videos but the video would not load (for example if your server is down or the email is read offline). The second fallback is for cases where email clients don’t support videos at all.

Comment: I see now. That'll teach me **not** to edit code at midnight before bed. PS: Seems like a useful answer, let's see what the Asker's feedback is.

Comment: This extra snippet helped! Thanks a ton!